# How can I conver SQL select statement to Python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, t-sql

I have my dataset 'df'.
How can I group data based on conditions using pandas?

In t-sql that would be:

```
select Producer, sum(Premim) as Premium
from df
where EffectiveDate BETWEEN '2018-01-01' and '2018-03-01'
AND PolicyType = 'New Business'
AND SICCode IN (4210,4211,4213)
GROUP BY Producer
Order by Premium DESC
```

[image]

What I tried:

## select top 10 Premium GroupBy PolicyNumber

```
df['Premium'].groupby(df['PolicyNumber']).sum().head(10)
```

Also tried:

```
select * by range of EffectiveDate
df[df["EffectiveDate"].isin(pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2018-03-28'))]
```

But how to compile everything in one block of code?

UPDATE:
Python data sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Producer': 'Prod1 Prod2'.split(),
                   'Premium': '1000 2000'.split(),
                   'EffectiveDate': '2018-01-01 2018-03-31'.split(),
                   'SICCode': '4120 4113'.split(),
                   'PolicyType': 'NewBusiness Renewal'.split()
                   })
print(df)
```

UPDATE:
Data sample can be found here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2jh8crbwkhkn82z/SampleData.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: @roganjosh I updated question and showed what I tried. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are using correct dtypes:

```
codes = ['4120','4211']
#        ^    ^ ^    ^
```

`DataFrame.query()` is picky in terms of case-sensitivity, so use lower case predicates `and`, `in` and use `==` instead of `=` (assignment in Python)

```
In [112]: qry = """'2018-01-01' <= EffectiveDate <= '2018-03-01' and PolicyType =='NewBusiness' and SICCode in @codes"""
     ...: df.query(qry).groupby('Producer', as_index=False)['Premium'].sum()
     ...:
Out[112]:
  Producer Premium
0    Prod1    1000
```

Comment: Gives me an error:
ValueError: multi-line expressions are only valid in the context of data, use DataFrame.eval

Comment: ` File "<unknown>", line 1
    '2018-01-01'<=EffectiveDate <='2018-03-01'AND PolicyType ='New Business'AND SICCode IN [4210 ,4211 ,4213 ]
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @Oleg, please provide a small sample data set (in CSV/TEXT/Python code format) in your question

Comment: So there is a way to upload csv/text file?

Comment: I shared sample of data via Dropbox